# Formatting date from decimal in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, cells

How do I format a decimal value like 1.30 as "1 year & 3 months" in Excel?

The value needs to remain the same but just needs to be displayed as 1 year & 3 months.

I need to do this just using cell formatting if possible. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I don't need code, I just need a formatting tip on how to do this. I've tried googling.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with just formatting. In any case 1.3 year is 1 year and 3.6 months (not 3 months).

Answer (score 2):

This might be a little bit convoluted, but here are the basics of how you can do it.

```
Decimal    Year           Month        Year and           Months              Combined
1.3    =FLOOR.MATH(A2) =(A2-B2)*10  =TEXT(B2,"# ")&D1   =TEXT(C2,"# ")&E1   =D2&" "&E2

1.3         1               3        1 Year and        3 Months         1 Year and 3 Months
```

The formulas are in the second row and are shown for explanation only. The results of those formulas are below. I referenced the headers in row one to create the concatenation of the text strings, but you could type them in formulas directly or place them in other cells and reference them there.

I took it to mean that .3 is the third month and not 3/10's of a year, so 1 year and eleven months would be 1.11. If that was not  the case, then you can play around with the math and you can get the answer.

Also as you run into the problem with truncating decimals 1.1 and 1.10, would be the same thing. I would suggest making it 1.01 and 1.1 then change the *10 to *100 in the month's column and that will give you the integer value you are looking for.